# Process for Testing a non-linear model

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, nonlinear-regression

If we have a non-linear regression model $y = x_1\beta_1 + x_1^2\beta_2 + e$ (where usual assumptions hold). Say that $y$ is your hourly wage and $x_1$ is the number of years of education.

How would I go about testing a hypothesis that we would expect someone with 10 years of education to have a wage of $20 (per hour)?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! The good news is that this is considered a linear model! Thus, how would you do it for any other linear model?

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/464ebe8e6b0703e41662b1a470f56dce) is a Python gist exemplifying how your model is linear in the parameters even though it is a quadratic in $x_1$. Note that the data is generated and not relevant to education or wage.